# Why does Ruby return for `str[-1..1]` what it does?

Tags: ruby, string

Suppose we have a string `str`. If `str` contains only one character, for example, `str = "1"`, then `str[-1..1]` returns `1`.
But if the `size` (`length`) of `str` is longer than one, like `str = "anything else"`, then `str[-1..1]` returns `""` (empty string).

Why does Ruby interpret string slicing like this?

Comment: my ruby version is ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]

Comment: If you wish to elaborate, please edit the question rather than using comments. "Ruby v2.3" is sufficient.

Comment: As you say, `"a"[-1..1] #=> "a"` and `"abf"[-1..1] => ""`, but in addition, `"ab"[-1..1]
 => "b"`.

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is just how ranges of characters work.

The range start is -1, which is the last character in the string. The range end is 1, which is the second position from the start.

So for a one character string, this is equivalent to 0..1, which is that single character.

For a two character string, this is 1..1, which is the second character.

For a three character string, this is 2..1, which is an empty string. And so on for longer strings.

Comment: Very good. If anyone is wondering about one character strings, `"a"[0..999] #=> "a"`.

Answer (score 3):

To get a non-trivial substring, the start position has to represent a position earlier than the end position.

For a single-length string, index `-1` is the same as index `0`, which is smaller than `1`. Thus, `[-1..1]` gives a non-trivial substring.

For a string longer than a single character, index `-1` is larger than index `0`. Thus, `[-1..1]` cannot give a non-trivial substring, and by default, it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Writing down the indices usually helps me:

```
#      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
str = 'a' 'n' 'y' 't' 'h' 'i' 'n' 'g' ' ' 'e' 'l' 's' 'e' #=> "anything else"
#     -13 -12 -11 -10 -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

You can refer to each character by either its positive or negative index. For example, you can use either `3` or `-10` to refer to `"t"`:

```
str[3]   #=> "t"
str[-10] #=> "t"
```

and either `7` or `-6` to refer to `"g"`:

```
str[7]  #=> "g"
str[-6] #=> "g"
```

Likewise, you can use each of these indices to retrieve `"thing"` via a range:

```
str[3..7]    #=> "thing"
str[3..-6]   #=> "thing"
str[-10..7]  #=> "thing"
str[-10..-6] #=> "thing"
```

`str[-1..1]` however would return an empty string, because `-1` refers to the last character and `1` refers to the second. It would be equivalent to `str[12..1]`.

But if the string consists of a single character, that range becomes valid:

```
#      0
str = '1'
#     -1

str[-1..1] #=> "1"
```

In fact, `1` refers to an index *after* the first character, so `0` would be enough:

```
str[-1..0] #=> "1"
```